# Using Trim function in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, plsql

I have a below values in a column of table:

```
Veracruz-Llave Federal Hwy 150
Campeche Federal Hwy 261
Puebla Federal Hwy 190
Morelos Federal Hwy 160
Puebla Federal Hwy 160
```

I would like to update the table such that state name before the string 'Federal Hwy' is deleted/removed.

Desired output would be:

```
Federal Hwy 150    
Federal Hwy 261    
Federal Hwy 190    
Federal Hwy 160
```

Ie., Remove anything before 'Federal Hwy'

Can TRIM() function help here?

Comment: Show us your complete stored procedure

Comment: Are you needing to update the data in a column, or when you select from it?  More info needed.

Comment: I would rather use regexp_replace: `regexp_replace(column,'(.*Federal Hwy)*(.*)', '\2' )`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are cleaning up addresses and need to do an update.  Test it first like this with some sample addresses:

```
select regexp_substr('Veracruz-Llave Federal Hwy 150', ' (Federal.*)$', 1, 1, null, 1 ) from dual;
```

Then make a backup of the table, and run (untested, use at your own risk) - this assumes ALL of your column data has a single space after the text you want to delete, it is the first space in the line and you want to keep the rest of the string:

```
update table set column_name = regexp_substr(column_name, ' (Federal.*)$', 1, 1, null, 1 );
```

This takes the first subgroup (whats in the parens) of the first occurrence of a pattern of a space, followed by 0 or more characters of any type anchored to the end of the line.  In other words keep everything after but not including the first space.

Edit: Amended example based on new info provided by the OP below.

Comment: your code works. However, I just noticed that some state routes have have more than 1 string before the string "Federal"

Comment: Just add "Federal" to the regex.  I amended the example.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REPLACE along with SUBSTR and INSTR

```
  SQL> create table states (name varchar2(200));
                insert into states values('Campeche Federal Hwy 261');
                insert into states values ('Puebla Federal Hwy 190');
                insert into states values('Morelos Federal Hwy 160');
                insert into states values ('Puebla Federal Hwy 160');
                commit;

            -- OUTPUT:
                    Table created.                                                                                                                       
                    1 row created.                                                                                                                            
                    1 row created.                                                                                                                            
                    1 row created.                                                                                                                              
                    1 row created.                                                                                                                                   
                    Commit complete. 

       --update table STATES to get only state
  SQL>update STATES
        set NAME = REPLACE
                    (NAME, 
                          SUBSTR(NAME,0,
                                    (INSTR(NAME,'Federal',1,1))-1
                                )
                        ,'');     
  --4 rows updated.  

  SQL> commit;                                                                                                               
    Commit complete.                                                                                                            

  SQL> select * from STATES;                                                                                                   
    NAME                                                                                                                        
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                        
    Federal Hwy 261                                                                                                             
    Federal Hwy 190                                                                                                             
    Federal Hwy 160                                                                                                             
    Federal Hwy 160
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to trim state names(i.e. first word) from string;
logic is use substr fuction to give require string, instr will return position of first space so that trimming can start from it.

```
update table_name set column_name = ltrim(substr(column_name, instr(column_name,' ')));
```